# Can I have the sender pay fees in a chained adaptive payment via paypal?

Tags: paypal

In the adaptive payments integration guide, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/, there is the following statement

Sender Pays the Fee

The sender can pay a fee for a simple payment, parallel payment, or a chained payment.

However when I try setteing FeesPayer to "SENDER" in a chained payment, I get
The fee payer SENDER cannot be used if a primary receiver is specified

which according to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/ is the expected behaviour since 1.6.0 of the API. Is this just an example of the docs being misaligned or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you setting up a regular chained payment or a delayed chained payment?  I'm wondering if maybe it works with a regular chained but not delayed.

Comment: I just tested it in the sandbox and it's giving me the same error either way.  Looks like it must be a doc error.  You could always submit a ticket to [PayPal MTS](http://www.paypal.com/mts) and see what they say about it.